# Data binding in angularjs after http call

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to bind some data I fetch with an Http call when user clicks a button. Data binding works fine when I use it outside of `test()` but it does not inside `test()` which gets called on a button click.
 What am I doing wrong?

```html
<head>
  <script>
    function test() {

    fetch(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {

                var response = myJson;
                var results = parseJSON(response);

                angular.module("blabla", [])

                    .controller("myController", function($scope) {
                        $scope.test= {};
                        $scope.test.title = "testttt!";
                    });
    });


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="blabla">
  <div class="search">
    <form id="search_form" method="get" onSubmit="return test()">
      <input type="text" class="_search" placeholder="Search" id="search_">
      <input title="Search" value="" type="submit" class="search_btn">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <h2>Welcome {{test.title}}</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `onSubmit="return test()"` by `onSubmit="test()"`

The Angular interpreter is trying to invoke the statement (I believe that it thinks it is a function) `return` (with parameters `test()`

Also, `test()` needs to be declared in the `$scope` of your controller `myController`.

It might be a good idea to get a skeleton demo Angular app and try to understand how it works by making small modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but removing the return keyword didn't solve it.

Comment: The problem is that your `temp()` functions just declared stand-alone, with no relationship to your controller (which you did not post). Move your controller into a separate file, if not already in one, and declare `temp()` within its `$scope`.

Comment: Try finding a simple demo code, or follow a tutorial, such as https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/  It's not too tough :-) Good luck